# How to format numbers in php

Tags: php

Hello i have this value `171024` and i want to make it `1,710.24` i tried the `number_format` but cant find the combination to give `1,710.24`.

The code i did is:

```
echo number_format("171024");
```

and the result is `171,024`

I followed this page: https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_string_number_format

but its limited not showing excaclty what i need.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us the code, and what it's outputting.

Comment: @Sammitch the output is `171,024`

Comment: Well, how would you usually turn the number 171024 into 1710.24?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to format `1710.24`, but you're starting with `171024` so you need to do some arithmetic first

Convert your string to a float, then divide by 100: `(float)"171024"/100`

Then format the result, give it two decimal places and set the decimal and thousands separators:

```
echo number_format((float)"171024"/100,2,".",",");  // 1,710.24
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/QMumY